# Problemas al verificar nombre existente (Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo mediante AJAX, un checker para ver sí el nombre de usuario existe o no. El problema que tengo ahora es que al pasar por el `input` envía datos en vacío. ¿Alguna solución?, intenté colocar `empty` en el archivo .php pero aún así ocurre.

```
// Ajax request
$('document').ready(function(){
  var username = 'username='+$("#username").val();
 $('#username').on('blur', function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: '/templates/new/includes/ajaxrequest/register.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {username},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
       $("span").html(data);
    }
  });
 });    
});

// Register.php
 <?php
define('BRAIN_CMS', 1); 
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/global.php';

if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $results = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $results->bindParam(':username', $user);
    $results->execute();
    if ($results->rowCount() > 0) {
      echo "taken"; 
    }else{
      echo 'not_taken';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes validar antes de enviar tu peticio `AJAX`;

```
// Ajax request
$('document').ready(function () {
    var username = 'username=' + $("#username").val();
    $('#username').on('blur', function () {
            if ($(this).val().length > 2) { // Validacion 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/templates/new/includes/ajaxrequest/register.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        username
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("span").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
    }
});
```

Acá lo que hice fue validar la longitud del texto que inserten sea mayor a 2, o el numero que desees.

De igual manera te aseguras en el `backend`;

```
// Register.php
<?php
define('BRAIN_CMS', 1);
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/global.php';

if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    if (strlen($user) > 2) { //Validacion
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
        $results = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $results->bindParam(':username', $user);
        $results->execute();
        if ($results->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "taken";
        } else {
            echo 'not_taken';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, otra pregunta que tengo o quizás la tenga que colocar en la misma publicación. ¿Alguna forma que salga la alerta o muestre la notificación al instante, es decir, en tiempo real?. Sin necesidad de click al input y después dar otro click en otro lugar de la página para que se muestre.

Comment: @Snowstorm Un placer servirte. con respecto a tu otra duda, debes formular una pregunta nueva ya que esto es otro tema, aunque te recomiendo que investigues un poco como hacerlo, al encontrar la solución, que estoy `99%` seguro que la encontraras, si tienes algún problema, no dudes en pasar por la comunidad.

Comment: Está bien amigo, gracias.

Comment: @Snowstorm Antes de marcharte recuerda que si esta respuesta soluciono tu problema, marcarla como respuesta aceptada, haciendo click en el `check` `✓` que sale a la izquierda ;)